# Defining labels in macro + linux system calls (nasm)

Tags: linux, system, call, nasm

I want to write a very simple macro using linux system call:

```
%macro hello_macro 1
section .rodata 
%%string1: dd "hello: ",0
section .bss
%%string2: resd 1
section .text
;global %%_start1
%%_start1:
mov dword[%%string1],%1 ;mov argument to string

    ;system call write in stdout
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,dword[%%string1]
mov edx,6
int 80h

    ;same
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,dword[%%string2]
mov edx,4                    ;it's 4 bytes so I assume it's 4 chars length.
int 80h 

%endmacro
```

I call it this way (in section .text):

```
hello_macro 0x00613233
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything (even errors)!

I compile it this way (without makefile):

```
nasm -f elf -o 2.o 2.s
gcc -o 2 2.o
```

2.c is the file. TNX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're not getting any errors, because you are referencing an undefined variable on this line:

```
mov dword[%%string],%1 ;mov argument to string
```

Assumedly that should be `%%string2`.

```
mov dword[%%string2],%1 ;mov argument to string
```

The other problem I can see is that ecx should be set to the address of the string your want to write. Like this:

```
mov ecx,%%string1
```

In your current code you're setting ecx to the first four bytes of that string.

Comment: It's because I copied only part of the program (let's say it's %%string2 and not %%string label.

Comment: In the rest of the program do you have a `_start` entry point somwhere?

Comment: Also, have you tried linking with `ld -o 2 2.o` rather than gcc?

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like your ecx assignments are also wrong.